# Is it possible to encrypt an uploaded video?

Tags: video

Is it possible to create functionality such that when someone uploads a video to my website, the system encrypts it and other people can't watch it even if they download it.

They would then require a private key to watch the video online.

Comment: What is related with python, php and ruby in this question? Please be more explanatory, I could not decrypt your post.

Comment: Though a bit naive in the way this is posed, it is not such a bad question after all! Cann't imagine why so many downvotes!

Answer (score 2):

[gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/) does a job like this. You can access the command from within your favorite language, [Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/) has a [tutorial for accessing gpg in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265).

But wouldn't it be more convenient for your users if they could watch the videos online? Then you would only need to control access to your page with a simple login system.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds very difficult.

It would be easier to force people to watch it online and simply limit access to the web page via authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For content protection. seems like, today there is no straight forward way to do this. However, there is an active interest inside HTML5 camp where some form of DRM can be applied for this.

See this: http://gigaom.com/video/mdialog-tackles-html5-video-security/